# How can I check if an item in "CheckedOut|Permanent" lock is checked out with the Core Service?

Tags: core-service, lock-type

I have a versioned item and its info object and I need to see whether it's checked out or not, however, when I view its info.LockType.Value, I see it has assigned "CheckedOut|Permanent".
How can I compare against it?
I've tried comparing against LockType.CheckedOut or LockType.Permanent and each returns false.

```
FullVersionInfo info = (FullVersionInfo)versionedItem.VersionInfo;

if (info.LockType.Value == LockType.CheckedOut)
{
     // I am not getting here when item is "CheckedOut|Permanent"}
```

Comment: I wonder if this is the 'explicit checkout' instead of the 'implicit checkout' when we open a Component?  Maybe the API devs didn't have 2 properties to set, so they combined these 2 values in 1 property?

Answer (score 7):

In the backend it's a .NET enum  with the "Flags" attribute specified so it's value can be a combination of the enum values.

Try this:

```
info.LockType.Value.HasFlag(LockType.CheckedOut)
```

Notice HasFlags was introduced in .NET 4.0, in older versions of .NET you have to use bit operations to check a specific bit.

Something like this:

```
(info.LockType.Value & LockType.CheckedOut) != 0
```

Comment: .HasFlag arrived with 3.5

Comment: Strange. I checked on MSDN, and there I can only choose .NET 4, .NET 4.5, and Silverlight. Oh well, a bit of bit manipulation has never harmed anyone. :)

Comment: Sorry - you are right. My mistake.

Answer (score 4):

As of SDL Tridion 2013 you do not need to use `FullVersionInfo`. Now each of the `RepositoryLocalObject` items has `LockInfo`. So you can use `component.LockInfo.LockType`, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Many thanks for all the answers!
As it turns out, the following code also accomplishes what I am looking for, as it will detect all possible locks an item can acquire.

```
if (LockType.None != info.LockType)
 { ...  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Andrey mentions, this can now be done using the `LockInfo` property on the item.

I've just successfully implemented this using the following code:

```
RepositoryLocalObjectData item = Client.Read(itemId, new ReadOptions { LoadFlags = LoadFlags.Expanded}) as RepositoryLocalObjectData;

//It the item is locked for any reason (Checked-out, in Workflow, etc.) then don't try to process it
if (item.LockInfo.LockType.Value != LockType.None)
{
    //Do something here.
}
```

Hope this helps.